# Assert that a method is called to bring an if condition under test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Here is an example where I am testing the line `if (true)`. But although the condition is obviously true, Moq tells me the method was never called.

```
    public class test
    {
        public virtual void start()
        {
            if (true)
                called();
        }

        public virtual void called()
        {

        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void QuickTest()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<test>();
        mock.Object.start();
        mock.Verify(t => t.start(), "this works");
        mock.Verify(t => t.called(), "crash here: why not called?");
    }
```

How do I test that the method call to `called()` has happened?

I thought Moq was the solution, but from the comments it looks like it isn't so I've made another example without any reference to Moq:

```
public class test
{
    public bool condition = true;

    public test(bool cond)
    {
        condition = cond;
    }

    public virtual string start()
    {
        var str = "somestuff";

        if (condition)
            str += called();

        str += "something more";
        return str;
    }

    public virtual string called()
    {
        return "something more";
    }
}

[Test]
public void ConditionTrue_CallsCalled()
{
    var t = new test(true);
    t.start();
    //syntax? t.HasCalled("called");
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("something more"));
}

[Test]
public void ConditionFalse_NoCall()
{
    var t = new test(false);

    t.start();

    //syntax? t.HasNotCalled("called");
    // Can't check this way because something more is already being added
    Assert.IsFalse(result.Contains("something more")); 
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Is it worthwhile?

Comment: .... Did you really mock the object you want to test? I mean, think about that for a second.

Comment: I'm running this exact code and the `Verify(t => t.start()` works but the `Verify(t => t.called()` doesn't. I must be missing something...

Comment: Do you know what a Mock is?

Comment: You can use `new Mock<test>() { CallBase = true }` to call the base implementation if that's what you want it to do, but I agree that you don't generally mock the class under test.

Comment: Heh that did the trick, thanks alot mike z. @Pierre-Luc: I'm new to Moqing, is it not a good idea to bring this `if (true)` under test or should I test it in another way?

Comment: Mocks are for simulating others objects, so you can test your class without any interference from the other classes. Basically, it creates an empty shell from an interface, without any logic. So mocking your class, i.e. clearing all the logic out of it, serves absolutely no purpose. [Read more about mocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault is trying to help you. Put the hammer down. Not everything is a nail.

Comment: Normally I would use `Assert.IsTrue` and check the return value of the method. In my case the return object is a `TagBuilder` where I can only access the `InnerHtml` property to check for example for the existence of a `<span>` string - which could have been added by other code. So I'd need to check for `<span class='x'>` but then my test knows everything about the inner method and that is what I wanted to avoid. Did I oversimplify my example or am I just not getting it? To be clear: I don't **need** to use Moq, I just need to get the `if (true)` under test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first piece of code:

`mock` is a mock object.  That means all the methods are overridden and do nothing.  So it's entirely normal that calling `mock.start()` doesn't do anything and `called()` is never called.

If you want to mock just `called()` and use the real implementation of `start()`, you need to do partial mocking.

But I would advise against that, I would even advise against trying to test just this class.  You will couple your test code too tightly to your implementation code.  Think about doing TDD: ask yourself what feature of your application breaks if that if test is not there.  Write a test against that feature, which should fail.  Then write the if test to fix the test.