# Abusing Moq to test an if condition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Considering the following class:

```
public class test
{
    public void start()
    {
        if (true)
            called();
    }

    internal protected virtual void called()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to bring the `if (true)` under test. My initial idea was to use Moq to Verify that `called()` was invoked. I ended up with this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public partial class TestMethodInvocation
{
    [Test]
    public void TestWithMoqVerify()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<test>() {CallBase = true};
        mock.Object.start();
        mock.Verify(t => t.called());
    }
}
```

I had some troubles getting this to work and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425163/assert-that-a-method-is-called-to-bring-an-if-condition-under-test) where I was adviced not to use Moq to mock the class under test.

So I added a subclass and used a property to test whether the method was called:

```
public class test2 : test
{
    public bool WasCalled { get; set; }

    internal protected override void called()
    {
        WasCalled = true;
    }
}

public partial class TestMethodInvocation
{
    [Test]
    public void TestWithSubclassProperty()
    {
        var test = new test2();
        test.start();
        Assert.IsTrue(test.WasCalled);
    }
}
```

Both approaches work but the Moq implementation is effectively half the amount of testing code as I don't need to create a subclass. Is it very bad to use Moq like this, or should I use another framework to do this kind of testing? Or is this the result of a problem in the design of my code?

Comment: You're supposed to test the class and mock all the dependencies. Then you test how the class under test is interacting with the mocks.

Comment: "I was adviced not to use Moq to mock the class under test" - no, you were advised not to mock the tested class, and not not to use Moq. In the second version you're still doing the same thing - you've mocked your class "test" with a subclass... It's not bad to use Moq like this, it's just strange to mock the class that you're testing.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Is it a bad idea to write such test in the first place?  I'm guessing my logic is flawed since I end up with 'strange' test code?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't test internals of the class. Test the external behaviour - if a class gives correct results, why do you care how does it achieve it? You use verify to verify calls one class makes on another class - because that is external behaviour and it is good to check, whether, for example, correct API calls are being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the real question you are asking is how do you test that the method `called` is executed within your `test` class?

To answer that you have to then ask yourself, "How will a `test` object be different after the method `called` is executed?"  Then, you write a unit test that verifies in an indirect manner that the object `test` has changed in the way expected.

Along with what everybody else has said, Moq is used in a way to isolate out code that is unimportant for a particular test. In your case, you DO not want to create a mock -- you need to test the actual code!

My answer is that if by calling `called` has no way for you to see how the `test` object has changed, then maybe you need to think the logic of what `called` is doing. Or, you need to apply further operations to `test` that will expose a different state that is testable.

For example, maybe the expected behavior is:

- If `foo()` is called after `called()` has been called, `Enabled` is
  true, BUT
- If `foo()` is called without `called()` ever being called, `Enabled` is false.

So, in your test you'll have to perform several operations (like calling `foo()`) on your class under test before you get it to a externally testable state:

```
var test = new test();
test.foo();
Assert(test.Enabled, Is.False);

var test = new test();
test.start();
test.foo();
Assert(test.Enabled, Is.True);
```

Comment: There is no such flag being set by `called` (not without duplicating the logic of `called` in the test). Hmm... But I could change the signature of `called` so that such test is possible. Looks like I was not at all trying to do the simplest thing again. (and I'm really bad at asking the right question)

Comment: Very good point! If "called" was doing something useful and externally visible, then this thing would've been verified by the test. Because this method does nothing, there is nothing to test and in such ill-formed situation it's hard to produce any test that makes sense. The question was how to test something that does nothing on a class that has no state.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of a debate whether you should write tests for call verification, I'm trying to steer clear from them, I'd rather test the external behavior. You'd test something and see if the desired result was achieved, without tapping into the internals. This is of course not always possible.

Now, having said that, I'm going to try to give you an example (the best way I can). Say that we have a class called `Greeter` - which is supposed to send an annoying SMS to all stackoverflow subscribers. Now, say that for sending the SMS you've written some other infrastructure code somewhere elsewhere (already tested and all). Say that this code will be an implementation of an interface called `IMessageService` (sorry if my example sucks):

```
public interface IMessageService
{
    void SendSMS(string message);
}
```

Additionally, say that you have a `SubscriberRepository` that would get you all the StackOverflow subscribers. Something like:

```
public interface ISubscriberRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Subscriber> GetStackOverflowSubscribers();
}
```

Here is your `Greeter` class:

```
public class Greeter
{
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    private readonly ISubscriberRepository _subscriberRepository;

    public Greeter(IMessageService messageService, ISubscriberRepository subscriberRepository)
    {
        _messageService = messageService;
        _subscriberRepository = subscriberRepository;
    }

    public void SendGreetingToStackOverflow()
    {
        IEnumerable<Subscriber> stackOverflowers = _subscriberRepository.GetStackOverflowSubscribers();

        foreach (Subscriber overflower in stackOverflowers)
        {
            _messageService.SendSMS("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

You see it's actually using the `IMessageService` to send the sms. At this point you want to (possibly) test if `SendSMS()` was called `x` amount of times. In this case the amount of times should be the same as the amount of StackOverflow subscribers. So your test would look like this:

```
[Test]
public void SendGreetingToStackOverflow_CallsIMessageServiceSendSMSTwoTimes()
{
    var mockMessageService = new Mock<IMessageService>();
    var mockSubscriberRepo = new Mock<ISubscriberRepository>();

    // we will mock the repo and pretend that it returns 2 subscibers
    mockSubscriberRepo
        .Setup(x => x.GetStackOverflowSubscribers())
        .Returns(new List<Subscriber>() {new Subscriber(), new Subscriber()});

    // this is the one we're testing, all dependencies are fake
    var greeter = new Greeter(mockMessageService.Object, mockSubscriberRepo.Object);

    greeter.SendGreetingToStackOverflow();

    // was it called 2 times (for each subscriber) ?
    mockMessageService.Verify(
        x => x.SendSMS("Hello World!"),
        Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

Again, sorry this is possibly not the BEST example, but it's been a long day and it's the best I can come up with :).

I hope it helps.

Comment: `without tapping into the internals`: that was exactly what I was trying to do. `called` had no observable side-effects unless I was to check the result for exactly what the `called` code did. I realize now that I'll have to change the way I write code in different ways. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example that makes some sense, as close to what are you trying to do as possible would be:

```
interface Callable
{
  void Called();
}

class Test
{
  public Test(Callable x)
  {
    this.callable = callable;
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    if (true)
      callable.Called();
  }

  private Callable callable;
}
```

Then the test would look like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public partial class TestMethodInvocation
{
  [Test]
  public void TestWithMoqVerify()
  {
    var callableMock = new Mock<Callable>();
    var test = new Test(callableMock);
    test.Start();
    callableMock.Verify(t => t.Called());
  }
}
```

Rephrasing my comment:

you shouldn't test internals of the class - test the external behaviour.